# Add record to a model upon create used in many models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, callback

I have a survey and I would like to add participants to a `Participant` model whenever a user answers to a question for the first time. The survey is a bit special because it has many functions to answer questions such as Tag words, Multiple choices and Open Question and each function is actually a model that has its own records. Also I only want the Participant to be saved once.

The Participant model is fairly simple:

```
class Participant < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :survey
  attr_accessible :survey_id, :user_id
end
```

The Survey model is also straightforward:

```
class Survey < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  has_many :participants, :through => :users
  has_many :rating_questions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :open_questions, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :tag_questions, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :user

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :open_questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rating_questions
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tag_questions
  ...
end
```

Then you have models such as `rating_answers` that belong to a `rating_question`, `open_answers` that belong to `open_questions` and so on.

So initially I thought for within my model `rating_answers` I could add `after_create` callback to add_participant

like this:

```
class RatingAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :rating_question
   after_create :add_participant
   ...
   protected
   def add_participant
     @participant = Participant.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :survey_id => Survey.find(params[:survey_id]))
     if @participant.nil?
       Participant.create!(:user_id => current_user.id, :survey_id => Survey.find(params[:survey_id]))
     end
   end
end
```

In this case, I didn't know how to find the survey_id, so I tried using the params but I don't think that is the right way to do it. regardles it returned this error

```
NameError (undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #<RatingAnswer:0x0000010325ef00>):
  app/models/rating_answer.rb:25:in `add_participant'
  app/controllers/rating_answers_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

Another idea I had was to create instead a module `Participants.rb` that I could use in each controllers

```
module Participants
  def add_participant
    @participant = Participant.where(:user_id => current_user.id, :survey_id => Survey.find(params[:survey_id]))
    if @participant.nil?
      Participant.create!(:user_id => current_user.id, :survey_id => Survey.find(params[:survey_id]))
    end
  end
end
```

and in the controller

```
class RatingAnswersController < ApplicationController
  include Participants
  def create
    @rating_question = RatingQuestion.find_by_id(params[:rating_question_id])
    @rating_answer = RatingAnswer.new(params[:rating_answer])
    @survey = Survey.find(params[:survey_id])
    if @rating_answer.save
      add_participant
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And I got a routing error

```
ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant RatingAnswersController::Participants):
```

I can understand this error, because I don't have a controller for participants with a create method and its routes resources

I am not sure what is the proper way to add a record to a model from a nested model and what is the cleaner approach.

Ideas are most welcome!

Comment: current_user is a helper that's accessible in views/controller alone. You need to pass it as a parameter into the model. Else, it ain't accessible in the models.

Comment: I also see that you ain't passing any rating-question data while creating the rating-answer object.

Comment: Thank you, you indicated a possible solution. I will post my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

current_user is a helper that's accessible in views/controller alone. You need to pass it as a parameter into the model. Else, it ain't accessible in the models. May be, this should help.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I ended up using the `after_create` callback but instead of fetching the data from the params, I used the associations. Also `if @participant.nil?` didn't work for some reason.

```
class RatingAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :rating_question
   after_create :add_participant
   ...
   protected
   def add_participant
    @participant = Participant.where(:user_id => self.user.id, :survey_id => self.rating_question.survey.id)
    unless @participant.any?
      @new_participant = Participant.create(:user_id => self.user.id, :survey_id => self.survey.rating_question.id)
    end
  end
end
```

The cool thing with associations is if you have deeply nested associations for instead

```
Survey has_many questions
Question has_many answers
Answer has_many responses
```

in order to fetch the survey id from within the responses model you can do

```
self.answer.question.survey.id
```

very nifty!